# Averaging all the rows of a massive pyspark dataframe when each row only contain a sparse vector

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I have a pyspark dataframe with 15 million rows and one column. 
Each row contains a sparse vector ( `Vectors.sparse` from `pyspark.ml.linalg`) `x` (vector size is 5000)

I want to obtain a dense vector, containing the mean of all the sparse vectors contained in each row.

I tried the following approach:

```
from pyspark.ml.stat import Summarizer
result = df.select(Summarizer.mean(df.x)).show(truncate=False)
```

but it takes hours.

Is there an efficient way to average all the rows of a dataframe, if each row only contains a sparse vector?